# Need information about particular kind of quotients of semisimple algebraic groups by free abelian discrete subgroups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties

Let me start with the simplest version of the question since already there I don't know anything.

For a complex number $q$, consider the quotient space $X_q:=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)\left/\left\{\left.\left(\begin{smallmatrix}q^n&0\\0&q^{-n}\end{smallmatrix}\right)\right|n\in\mathbb Z\right\}\right.$ of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$ by the cyclic subgroup generated by $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}q&0\\0&q^{-1}\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. It is a complex variety, presumably quasiprojective (part of the question), containing a copy of the elliptic curve $E_q:=\mathbb C^*/q^{\mathbb Z}$ (via identifying $\mathbb C^*$ with a copy of the maximal torus in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$). In fact there is a(n almost always infinite) cyclic covering $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)\twoheadrightarrow X_q$, with the inverse image of $E_q\subset X_q$ being that maximal torus.

I want to know everything about this $X_q$ - whether it is isomorphic to something well known and studied before, whether the simple algebraic group structure of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$ implies any additional structure on $X_q$, what properties does the family $(X_q)_{q\in\mathbb C^*}$ have. Especially this: clearly group structure of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$ does not descend to $X_q$ since the cyclic subgroup is not normal -- in fact in a sense $E_q$ is the "largest possible subgroup" of $X_q$ (the normalizer of that cyclic subgroup is the torus); still, $X_q$ contains the abelian variety $E_q$. Can one obtain a description of $X_q$ in the style "abelian variety and something else", "minimally containing that abelian variety"?

The general question stems from this last (very vague) one. Given a semisimple algebraic group $G$ with maximal torus $T$, any choice of a lattice $L\subset T$ gives a similar variety $X_L:=G/L$ containing a copy of the abelian variety $T/L$.

What kind of variety is $X_L$? What are properties of the family $X_L$ as $L$ varies? And when also $T$ varies? Do such things occur naturally in any contexts?

My motivation is as vague as the question itself. I will provide it if pressed :D

A refinement/adjustment after comments/chat with Laurent Moret-Bailly: I should say "choice of a lattice $L\subset T$ such that $T/L$ admits a structure of an abelian variety". Accordingly, part of the question is: if this happens, does it follow that $G/L$ admits a structure of a quasiprojective variety?

Comment: Why "presumably quasiprojective"? I find it hard to believe.

Comment: @abx well if it is not I would like to know why :P

Comment: @abx PS in fact at the first glance it even seems surprising that ${\mathbb C}^\times/q^{\mathbb Z}$ is an algebraic variety, let alone projective, no?

Comment: Indeed it is something of a miracle that $\mathbb{C}^\times/q^\mathbb{Z}$ "is" algebraic, and in fact the higher-dimensional analogue is false, i.e. if $T=\mathbb{C}^g$ and $L\subset T$ is a lattice, then $T/L$ can be any complex torus (not in general algebraic if $g\geq2$).

Comment: Also, one should assume $\vert q\vert\neq1$: if $q$ is a root of unity, we get the trivial case where $q^\mathbb{Z}$ is finite, and if $\vert q\vert=1$ but $q$ has infinite order, then $q^\mathbb{Z}$ is not a closed subgroup.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Last remark understood completely, $|q|=1$ is an exceptional case. As for your first remark, here I understand less. "My" $T$ is a *multiplicative* torus, a product of copies of $\mathbb C^\times$ rather than of $\mathbb C$, and there I don't know what happens with quotients by discrete subgroups of full rank. I mean it is sort of "half way closer to being algebraic" compared to the additive thing, whatever that means.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: If $\Gamma\cong\mathbb{Z}^{2g}$ is an (additive) lattice in $\mathbb{C}^{g}$, any $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of $\Gamma$ contains a $\mathbb{C}$-basis of $\mathbb{C}^{g}$. This implies that $\mathbb{C}^{g}/\Gamma$ is isomorphic (as complex Lie group) to $(\mathbb{C}^{g}/\mathbb{Z}^{g})/L$ where $L\cong\mathbb{Z}^{g}$ is the image of $\Gamma$. Since $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{C}^\times$, "your" $T/L$'s are exactly the same as their additive analogues.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: And sorry, I just realized I had written $T=\mathbb{C}^g$ but meant $T=(\mathbb{C}^\times)^g$.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Well yes but $\mathbb C/\mathbb Z\cong\mathbb C^\times$ is not algebraic, right? So in principle starting from $(\mathbb C^\times)^g$ is sort of less demanding than starting from $\mathbb C^g$. Maybe I should modify/add a question whether if $T/L$ is an abelian variety this could be used somehow to realize $G/L$ as a quasiprojective variety...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20149/discussion-between-laurent-moret-bailly-and--).